# mysql - procedure to insert and then select inserted record

Tags: mysql, syntax

This works perfect in the sql query window... but it fails when I try to throw it into a stored procedure..

query:

```
INSERT INTO Dulce(userid, type, window) VALUES (pUserId, pType, pWindow);

SELECT  P.*, 
        U.Username, 
        U.Name 
FROM Dulce P 
INNER JOIN User U ON P.Userid = U.Userid 
WHERE DulceId = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

The error when creating procedure just says that it's around

```
SELECT  P.*, 
            U.Username, 
            U.Name
```

and to check my syntax

Comment: How about you show the entire code?

Comment: `Userid` or `userid` ??? share the complete error message

Comment: @Naruto I'm creating the procedure with the phpMyAdmin designer.. that's the entire stored procedure code..

Comment: @devpro the case doesn't affect in insert. I mentioned it works perfectly in the regular sql query window. It would have failed there. The error message shows the entire sql statement i put up there then says "MYSQL said: #1065 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual.... right syntax near `SELECT  P.*, 
        U.Username, 
        U.Name 
FROM Dulce P 
INNER JOIN`

Comment: and where `DulceId` this column exist in whch table?

Comment: maybe u need backtick for this table `User`

Comment: @devpro pk of dulce. I really dont think my sql is wrong becauseit runs. Was just thinking I was missing something about stored procedures and it was dumb. Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe u need backtick for this table `User`

Comment: @devpro just tried that and no luck. It's weird because the procedure will save with the individual statements but when I put both in the procedure which I need to... error

Comment: Then why is this tagged as PHP if you don't have any php code?

Comment: bro ,can u show the DB structure for both tables?

Comment: @devpro regardless of the structure I tried simply saving the insert and then select * from Dulce and it also fails. Now when I create the procedure in code... it treats the select as something that's outside of the procedure. So it saves the insert and then runs the select. Maybe I need the begin and end brackets for the stored procedure?

Comment: ohh , it means insert record is working fine here

Comment: @Walker maybe you shouldn't delete tags before telling me my comment is useless...

Answer (score 0):

you need a delimiter ; in the select statement.

Also it is better to save LAST_INSERT_ID() to a variable and use the variable in the select.

Comment: a delimiter after the select statement? I tried that and nothing

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my profile was to do the following

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE spDulce(specify parameters here)
BEGIN

Stored procedure queries here ended with a ;

END//
```